# Cannot log in via a display manager on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, display-manager

I updated `libc` on my Debian (Jessie) and with it hundreds of packages. Now I can't sign in using a display manager. After entering password and signing in it loads with a black screen and then pushes me back to the display manager.

- Logging in via a virtual terminal and `startx` with my desktop environments (xfce, xmonad) still works.
- I installed another display manager (gdm, lightdm, xdm) and tried to log in with different users (including users with empty sessions) and I even replaced systemd with init, but that didn't help. And I installed a fresh xorg.
- I installed not just libc, but the development files `libc-dev-bin` in this one step. So there are even more new packages.
- My system is multiarch. Got i386 and amd64 packages installed.
- I have one screen and use the Nvidia card and proprietary drivers via bumblebee. Usually everything runs on the Intel graphics card.
- Years ago, the system was an Aptosid. But I changed all repository sources to Debian. After many updates, all packages should be from a Debian repo by now, I guess.
- I don't know if its a bug, but I can't start a terminal emulator on X, which has been started with `startx`. I have this issue since some years but it wasn't a problem. Running a terminal as root still works on any X.
- It has installed some `libwayland-*` packages, but i don't have weston installed.
- I updated some libpam and libdbus packages now. No difference.
- I checked the auth logs and other logs, but i couldn't find anything useful. Suggestions where I should search next?
- [apt log of the update.](http://lpaste.net/106090)

Edit:

- The display disables and enables while black screen. Maybe an attempt to change screen resolution.
- In *~/.xsession-errors* there is `OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000105f, you have 10001090`. Maybe it's the issue, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Did you check Xorg log (/var/log/Xorg.0.log or similar) for the reason of session crashing?

Comment: @zagrimsan There is no marked error in the Xorg log. But its suspicious that there is no note for a successful terminated Xorg, like in the other logs.

Comment: libc is a major component of the system.  Have you rebooted since the upgrade?  Weird things can happen when you change the foundation of the system.

Comment: @lornix I rebooted for every try. So roughly twenty times.

Comment: You might try reinstalling the video driver.  I had an issue where the simplistic display manager login screen worked, but the accelerated video graphics (NVidia) did not, producing the same kind of login->black->back to login type of response.  It can be done through a console (Ctrl-Alt-F1) if need be.

Comment: @lornix Its was often a mess to update the video driver, so i only update it for a good reason. But there is no evidence that the X tries to use the alternative graphics card. No entry in the X log and no light from the graphics switch indicator. Also bumblebee hides the graphics card. So its rather unlikely that this will help.

Comment: Since `startx` works but *dm doesn't, I'd check what is the difference in how the display manager attempts to start the session vs. how `startx` does it. This might of course be hard to figure out if the session dies immediately. Also compare Xorg log between successful start and a failing one, as there might be a clue.

Comment: The error in `.xsession-errors `is worth checking out, too. Check if there are any unresolved package conflicts in the system... or if there are some components that you have compiled manually or which otherwise don't originate in the repository, which you probably should now recompile.

Comment: I installed a new `libc` today. Everything works now.